# Ascii to Decimal In Memory, Would there be a bitwise shift answer?

Tags: c++, c

My question: 
I would like to change the Ascii (hex) in memory to a Decimal Value by shifting or any other way you know how?

I would like a function to assign the memory as follows:

From (Input): 
Example Memory: 32 35 38 00 (Ascii 258) 
Example Pointer: +var 0x0057b730 "258" const char *

To (Output)(The ANSWER I am looking for): 
Example Memory: 02 01 00 00 
Example Pointer: &var 0x0040f9c0 {258} int * 
Example Int: var 258 int

This function will (NOT) produce my answer above: 
This function will produce a Decimal (600) answer and a Hex(258) answer.

```
int Utility::AsciiToHex_4B(void* buff)
{
    int result = 0, i = 0;
    char cWork = 0;

    if (buff != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            cWork = *((BYTE*)buff + i);
            if (cWork != NULL)
            {
                if (cWork >= '0' && cWork <= '9')
                    cWork -= '0';
                else if (cWork >= 'a' && cWork <= 'f')
                    cWork = cWork - 'a' + 10;
                else if (cWork >= 'A' && cWork <= 'F')
                    cWork = cWork - 'A' + 10;

                result = (result << 4) | cWork & 0xF;
            }
        }
        return result; // :) Good
    }
    return result; // :( Bad
}
```

I've seen a lot of answers and questions about changing Ascii To Int or Ascii To Hex or even Ascii to Decimal and none of them answer the question above.

Thanks for any help you may provide.

Comment: there is no "ASCII 258" http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @Anders K. Yes, I only pointed out that the bytes 32 35 38 00 (Ascii) represent 258. However, thank you for commenting. Still awaiting answer.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. The function will produce exactly one answer, and given `"258"` it produces 600, which is the decimal value of hexadecimal 258.

Comment: if i understand correctly you want to convert a string "258" to an integer? like atoi("258"); or do you want to convert it to a string with hex characters in it? dont understand the hex reference. hex or dec is just a way of representing a value, the stored value is the same

Comment: When you say "any other way you know how", what's wrong with just using sscanf()? Is there some reason you need/want to use << ?

Comment: @molbdnilo - The function above will produce the wrong value (600) int as a return, also the memory of that function is: 58 02 00 00 (which is 600) ... However as Input, I feed a string "258" or char* which ever makes you happy :)... Reread the question a few times. You will get it.

Comment: @John F, I was curious if there was such a way to do it by shifting.

Comment: @DebugMechanic Hexadecimal 258 *is* 600. What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @Anders K, The reason for the hex and dec reference is to make it clear I want a particular memory resultant above.

Comment: @molbdnilo, the memory layout is not correct for what I want.

Comment: Re "I was just curious", well, yeah, there's >>got<< to be some way to do it using shifts, but it wouldn't be a very "natural" way. For example, as hobb's answer points out, just do rightmost-digit + 10*(middle-digit + 10*(leftmost-digit)). And, if you >>really, really<< want, you can do the accumulates and multiplies by way of shift operations. But that'll be awfully, awfully ugly (maybe even win you the obfuscated c code contest:).

Comment: @John F, it seems like I've stumped people with a memory layout requirement. See most people use a c standard lib function or typecast it. Maybe even a windows API to help them. I'm looking for a manual approach. Something that tweaks the bytes and lays out the memory correctly. The memory requirement is in the post above. Along with the required input and output.

Comment: I don't get the connection to `02 01 00 00`. It sounds like you want hexadecimal '258' to convert to 258 rather than 600.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, the input: 32 35 38 00 should give you an output: 02 01 00 00 without using the c standard library or any windows api or typecasting.

Comment: But if your input is hexadecimal 258 (i.e. the number *six hundred*), how can it become *two hundred and fifty-eight*? Is your input string actually the decimal representation?

Comment: "the Ascii (hex) in memory" sounds like a misconception to me. In your example you want the string "258" to be converted to the `int` value `258`. Which of the two should represent an hexadeciaml number? Probably none of those. In what base 02 01 00 00 -> 258?

Comment: @Bob__ 02 01 00 00 -> 258 is base 10

Comment: @molbdnilo, char* string = "258"; (input), int result = 258; (output).

Comment: You probably meant 258 base 10  = 102 base 16.

Comment: @DebugMechanic It seems that the root of the problem is that your input is decimal, but you're interpreting it as hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

"I would like to change the Ascii (hex) in memory to a Decimal Value by shifting.."
No, shifting won't help you here.

"...or any other way you know how?"
Yes as you say there are questions already answering that.
(in short you need to replace your shift operation with adding cWork times the correct base ten (1,10,100) and get it right with endianess. But just use an existing answer.)

Comment: your answer is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for the computer decimal and hex make no difference as the number is store in binary format anyway and it is presented to the user as a needed by different print functions. If I understood your problem correctly, this should simplify your life since you need to convert the c-string only to one of the two formats internally. You can then display the number in decimal or hex format as the client desires.

Normally, when I do those things by myself, I convert a string to a decimal variable working from the units up to the higher order numbers:

```
 char* str="258";
 uint8_t str_len=3;
 uint16_t num=0;
 for(uint8_t i=str_len-1;i>=0;--i)
 {
    uint16_t val=str[i]-'0';     //convert value
    uint16_t mult=10*st_len-i+1; //first round multiplier is 0, you could use base 16 instead of base 10 but I found it more laborious
    num+=val*(mult==0? 1 : mult);  //multiply the value by 1, 10 ... this is your decimal shift
 }
```

Please take the above untested code just as a reference for a solution, it can be done in a much better and more compact way.

Once you have the number in binary format you can manipulate it. You can divide it by 16 (mind the remainders) to obtain an hexadecimal representation of the same quantity

Finally, you can convert it back to to string as follows:

```
for(uint16_t i=str_len-1; num>0 ; num= num/10, --i)
{
    CHAR8 n = num % 10+'0';  //converts a decimal number to a decimal string, use base 16 for the hex
    char_buffer[i]=n;
}
```

You could achieve a similar result also with atoi and similar, which have a lot of side effects in case of failed conversion. Left/right shifting might not help you as much, this operation is like elevating a number to a power of two (or taking the log2, for a right shift) with an as larger exponent as the number of shifts. I.e. `unit8_t n = 1<<3` is like doing `2^3` and I don't think that pointer address is relevant for you.

Hope this suggestion can guide you forward

Comment: thank you. I'm looking over the code now. I'll play around with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much got the correct algorithm. You can left shift with 4 or multiply with 16, same thing. But you need to do this for every byte except the last one. One way to fix that is to set result to 0, then each time in the loop, do the shift/multiply of the result before you add something new.

The parameter should be an array of char, const qualified since the function should not modify it.

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int AsciiToHex (const char* buf)
{
  unsigned int result = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i<4 && buf[i]!='\0'; i++)
  {
    result*=16;

    if(buf[i] >= '0' && buf[i] <= '9')
    {
      result += buf[i] - '0';
    }
    else if(buf[i] >= 'a' && buf[i] <= 'f')
    {
      result += buf[i] - 'a' + 0xA;
    }
    else if(buf[i] >= 'A' && buf[i] <= 'F')
    {
      result += buf[i] - 'A' + 0xA;
    }
    else
    {
      // error handling here
    }
  }

  return result;
}

int main (void)
{
  _Static_assert('Z'-'A' == 25, "Crap/EBCDIC not supported.");

  printf("%.4X\n", AsciiToHex("1234"));
  printf("%.4X\n", AsciiToHex("007"));
  printf("%.4X\n", AsciiToHex("ABBA"));

  return 0;
}
```

Function that could have been useful here is `isxdigit` and `toupper` from ctype.h, check them out.

Since the C standard does in theory not guarantee that letters are adjacent in the symbol table, I added a static assert to weed out crap systems.